# Toggle navigation drawer with a ButtonView

Tags: android

I am using navigation drawer. I have hidden the action bar using a`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"`. So i am able to slide the drawer using swipe only. I want to create a button. On button click i want to show the drawer. I have googled but couldn't find much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Call openDrawer on your onClick:

> public void openDrawer (View drawerView)
>
> Open the specified drawer view by animating it into view.
>
> Parameters drawerView Drawer view to open

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View)

Answer (score 1):

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

and to close :

```
drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final ImageView toolbar1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Toolbar1);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);




        toolbar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            }
        });
```